# Drupal Notifications API: notifications_user_get_subscriptions

Tags: drupal, notifications

This is the signature per [Acquia's documentation](http://library.acquia.com/api/function/notifications_user_get_subscriptions/atrium):

```
notifications_user_get_subscriptions($uid, $event_type, 
      $oid, $object = NULL, $refresh = FALSE)
```

I have [used this method before](http://drupal.org/node/937842) to get node-level subscriptions for a user. I cannot figure out what to pass for parameter 4 if I want to get subscriptions for a specific content type only. This call returns all content type subscription:

```
notifications_user_get_subscriptions($author->uid, 'node', 'type');
```

What should parameter 4 be for this? The 'type' is simply 'forum' in the database, but passing the string 'forum' does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until there is an answer to this question, I resorted to iterating through the results and testing the 'type' field. I posted the solution [here](http://drupal.org/node/954754).